# What is deafult_name argument in tensorflow's tf.name_scope()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Title is all there is

The documentation says :

> Args:
>
> name: The name argument that is passed to the op function.
>
> default_name: The default name to use if the `name` argument is `None`.
>
> values: The list of `Tensor` arguments that are passed to the op function.

Which is not making it very clear to me as to what is default_name argument's purpose

Answer (score 0):

Well, its been said quite properly

> `default_name`: The default name to use if the `name` argument is None

If the value of `name` is none, then the `default_name` value is used as name.

Atleast one among `name` and `default_name` must not be None, or it will throw the following error

```
ValueError: At least one of name (None) and default_name (None) must be provided.
```

Comment: what is the point of this? why dont we have a default_name_1 which, the name defaults to if the value of name and default_name are both None?